# Particular integral for inhomogeneous term $\cos(ax)\sin(bx)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a second order ODE with the term in the question as its inhomogeneous component, what trial solutions are suggested for finding the particular integral?

I have tried to 'complexify' the ODE by trying the trial solution $\cos(ax)e^{ibx}$ (with the intention of taking  the imaginary part of the resulting particular integral), but so far it's taken 3 pages of algebra and I have yet to reach an answer. I struggle to believe there isn't a more elegant solution.

NB $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the trigonometric identity,
$$ \cos(ax)\sin(bx) = \frac 1 2 \sin ((a + b)x) - \frac 1 2 \sin((a - b)x).$$
The right-hand side is free of annoying products!